# bootstrap - button with onclick function inside tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

As stated in title. Im trying to create a tooltip which will have some buttons inside. The problems is with the onclick function, which is somehow not working. This is the actual code I have.

```
$('#button_nowtime').popover({
            trigger: 'click',
            html: 'true',
            title:  "<b>Čas</b>",
            content: 
            function() {
                var returnstring="",button;
                    for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++){
                        button = document.createElement("a");  
                        button.innerText = fileNametoButtonTime(files[i]);
                        button.onclick = (function() {
                            var currentID = i;
                            return function() { 
                                alert("asd"); currentTimeIndex=currentID;  setNowTimeButton(); drawImage(); $('#button_nowtime').popover('hide');
                            }
                        })();
                        button.href="#";
                        returnstring+=button.outerHTML;
                        returnstring+=" | ";
                    }
                return returnstring;
            }
        });
```

The buttons appear in the tooltip but not react to the onclick function.

Comment: As you're already using jQuery, you might as well use it here as it'll make your life easier! `$(document).on('click', '.popover a', function(){}`

Comment: hm, I added it like this
    $(document).on('click', '.popover a', function(){
           alert("asd");
          });
and it didnt helped :/

Comment: Answered & Updated, don't forget to mark if it's correct for you, as you haven't seem to have done that for any other of your questions!

Answer (score 2):

I've adjusted your original question (**Demo Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/WfcM9/) to use jQuery to instead create the buttons and event handling.

With jQuery, it'll be adding the buttons to the DOM, giving them an class then outside the `popover()` function, give it a `$(document).on('click', 'classname')` for the document to wait for.

### With jQuery `.on('click')`

```
<script>
var files = [ "FileOne", "FiletWO" ],
    options = { 
       trigger: 'click',
       html: 'true',
       title:  "<b>Čas</b>",
       content:  function() {
           var $buttonsContainer = $('<div />');
           for( var i=0; i< files.length; i++ ) {

                  var addLink = $('<a>').addClass('fileclick btn btn-default')
                                        .attr( 'data-id', files[i] )
                                        .html( files[i] );
               
                  $buttonsContainer.append( addLink );                   
               }
               return $buttonsContainer;
           }
       };

    /**
     *  Create the Popover with above Options
    **/
    $('#button_nowtime').popover(options);

    /**
     * Listen for the Class Click on the buttons created.
    **/
    $(document).on('click', '.fileclick', function() {
         alert( $(this).data('id') ); 
         //Alerts FileOne or FileTwo
     });

</script>
```

**Fiddle Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/M2HQD/3/

Comment: doing `$(document).on('click', ...` did it for me as opposed to `$('.parent').on('click'...` Thanks! man i love the internets.